# Creating single state object from multiple stores data with Svelte derived store

Tags: svelte, svelte-3, sveltekit, svelte-component, svelte-store

I tried implementing a custom Svelte store, which would allow me to "throw" one single state object at the subscribing page. Here's an example code I prepared:

```js
import { derived, writable } from 'svelte/store'
import SomeOtherStore from '$stores/otherstore.js'
import { page } from '$app/stores'

const initialState = {
    loading: true,
    items: [],
    param: null,
}

const createPageStore = () => {
    // Create main store since derived store cannot be updated, set initial state
    const mainStore = writable(initialState)
    const { update } = mainStore

    // instantiate other store needed to construct page state
    const someOtherStore = SomeOtherStore()

    function someKindOfFunctionModifyingState() {
        // Need to update the state of items derived from SomeOtherStore, but the items do not exist here as the state was not propagated to the main store
        update(state => {
            return {
                ...state,
                items: state.items.map(stringItem => stringItem.capitalizeFirst())
            }
        })
    }

    // combine stores in order to construct page state
    const { subscribe } = derived([mainStore, page, someOtherStore], ([$mainStore, $page, $someOtherStore]) => {
        const { someItems, loading } = $someOtherStore
        
        return {
            ...$mainStore,
            loading: $mainStore.loading || loading,
            param: $page.url.searchParams.get('param'),
            items: someItems,
        }
    })

    return {
        someKindOfFunctionModifyingState,
        // return subscribe method from derived store
        subscribe,
    }
}

let instance

export default function PageStore() {
    return instance ?? (instance = createPageStore())
}
```

***mainStore** is how I thought I would be able to do this, since **derived** **stores cannot be updated***

As you can see, I need to construct the example items in my state object using data provided by `SomeOtherStore`.

##### The problem I have is that when I need to update the state of those items, I cannot do it because `items` array is empty in `mainStore` and I don't know how to pass the resulting derived state to the `mainStore`.

Obviously to no surprise if I try to set the final derived state to `mainStore` from within the derived store function, it results in a loop.

```html
<script>
  import PageStore from '$stores/pageStore.js'

  const store = PageStore()
  
</script>


{#each $store.items as item}
  <span>{item}</span>
{/each}
<button on:click={store.someKindOfFunctionModifyingState}>
  Click to capitalize first letter
</button>
```

*example usage in page component*

**TL;DR** Basically my need is to be able to create single object state combined from multiple stores and be able to update that state when for example click events happen.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I figured out I can subscribe to the derived store inside PageStore, just tested it and it works, but I feel like it's not the prettiest solution and seems like it defeats the purpose

Comment: It would help if you could cut down your example to something more simple and self-contained, ideally with a additional link to a functioning [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```js
 const { subscribe } = derived(...
```

write

```js
 const combined = derived(...
```

That would allow the `someKindOfFunctionModifyingState` function to use the [get](https://svelte.dev/docs#run-time-svelte-store-get) utility.

```js
import { get } from "svelte/store";

function someKindOfFunctionModifyingState() {
  const $combined = get(combined);
  mainStore.update(($mainStore) => ({ 
    ...$mainStore,
   items: $combined.items.map(stringItem => stringItem.capitalizeFirst())
  }))
}
```

Using `get` has a small performance overhead, but that's negligible for click events

Comment: That's a good idea, I have thought about it myself actually, but it does not suit my needs well. Each of the custom stores I am combining expose their own methods, like "refresh" method. So for example whenever I need to reload data from particular sets of endpoints, I call refresh method and expect other stores relying on that store data to update their state

Comment: I see, you might want to look into normalizing your state https://redux.js.org/usage/structuring-reducers/normalizing-state-shape
 and use `derived` as "selector" combine the data.